How should I fix the openssl wrong for buildozer
This is the wrong
[INFO]:    # Installing pure Python modules
[INFO]:    *** PYTHON PACKAGE / PROJECT INSTALL STAGE FOR ARCH: arm64-v8a ***
[INFO]:    The requirements (kivmob, kivy_garden, kivymd) don't have recipes, attempting to install them with pip
[INFO]:    If this fails, it may mean that the module has compiled components and needs a recipe.
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build
[DEBUG]:   -> running python3 -m venv venv
[INFO]:    Upgrade pip to latest version
[DEBUG]:   -> running bash -c source venv/bin/activate && pip install -U pip
[DEBUG]:        Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
[DEBUG]:        Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.2.1)
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
[DEBUG]:        Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
[DEBUG]:        Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
[INFO]:    Install Cython in case one of the modules needs it to build
[DEBUG]:   -> running bash -c venv/bin/pip install Cython
[DEBUG]:        Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
[DEBUG]:        Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
[DEBUG]:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
[DEBUG]:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
[DEBUG]:        WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
[DEBUG]:        Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Exception in thread background thread for pid 83012:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1256, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 685, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 104, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 163, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 528, in build_recipes
    run_pymodules_install(
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 713, in run_pymodules_install
    shprint(sh.bash, '-c', (
  File "/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/ivan/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install Cython'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/cython/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=com.gao.mapex', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivymd,kivy_garden,kivmob', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL2_GUI_APPS_ENABLED = '1'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu-22.04'
#     NAME = 'Lance-Yu'
#     PWD = '/mnt/d/python'
#     LOGNAME = 'ivan'
#     MOTD_SHOWN = 'update-motd'
#     HOME = '/home/ivan'
#     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/248_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     ANDROID_HOME = '/home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'ivan'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000/'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = ('/home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/ivan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu22.04LTS_2204.5.10018.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/VMware/VMware Workstation/bin/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Oculus/Support/oculus-runtime:/mnt/c/VulkanSDK/1.3.275.0/Bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common '
 'Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files (x86)/AMD/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI '
 'Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA '
 'Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Python27/Scripts:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot/jre/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-17.0.10.7-hotspot/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/MySQL/MySQL Server '
 '8.0/bin:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/Documents/cmake-3.26.4:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Gradle/gradle-8.5/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WireGuard/:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/3D '
 'Objects/ffmpeg-7.0.2-full_build/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/Documents/Handle/:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/:/mnt/c/Python27:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.2/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition '
 '2022.2.1/bin:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.3/bin:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/JetBrains/PyCharm '
 '2024.1.2/bin:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS '
 'Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/Documents/clearcmd.bat:/mnt/c/Users/AAA/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools')
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     PULSE_SERVER = 'unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'
#     _ = '/home/ivan/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/ivan'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/ivan/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/mnt/d/python/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/ivan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2 

then I ask chatgpt it talls me that's the openssl error, but it is work on the simple python in wsl(ubuntu), and also I have try buildozer android clean before, but it didnt work too.
I fix this error for a day.
And I use the ubuntu of wsl, I dont know why I get this error, when I use openssl in command it work very good.
How should I do to fix it?
ivan@Lance-Yu:/mnt/d/python$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

